# Parameter does not exist as a named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

My query is like this:

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select c.email from Contact c where c.contactNo =:contactNo");
    query1.setInteger("contactNo", 22);
```

The error I got is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Parameter contactNo does not exist as a named parameter in [select
>   c.email from Contact c where c.contactNo = ?]

It is working fine with

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select c.email from Contact c where c.contactNo = ?");
    query.setInteger(0, 22);
```

Why 1st query is not working?

Answer (score 4):

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select c.email from Contact c where c.contactNo =:contactNo");
query.setParameter("contactNo", 22);
```

try using setParameter instead of setInteger

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without any text, answers like this appears in the Low Quality Review Queue. This means that there's a risk your answer is deleted by what's known as robo-reviewers. I don't know anything about this topic so I can't really tell if it is low quality or not, but I suggest you add a small paragraph stating what is different from your code and the OP's post. Preferably with an explanation of why this works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a space before your parameter:

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select c.email from Contact c where c.contactNo = :contactNo");
query.setInteger("contactNo", 22);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Just Try this 


    **Step 1--:** Add How many parameter you need just add in hashmap
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    HashMap param_List=new HashMap();
    param_List.put("contactNo",22);

    
    **Step 2--:** Just You pass your Query
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Query query1 = session.createQuery("select c.email from Contact c where c.contactNo =:contactNo");


  **Step 3--:** What ever Data type is no matters but get an output.
  -------------------------------------------------------------------

    for(Object paramKey : param_List.keySet())
    {
    query1.setParameter(paramkey.toString(), param_List.get(paramKey);
    }


 **Step 4--:**
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    String finalResult=query1.getSingleResult().toString();
```